# get all users shopping cart

Tags: magento, migration, shopping-cart

I'm trying to migrate all user's carts to another system.

Is there a way to obtain every item in the shopping cart for every user?
What I need is only the product and customer IDs

Comment: What Magento are you using? You realy need it from cart or from order?

Comment: I'm using Magento 1.7, I need it from the cart.

Comment: Not all items in quote collection are in carts. To get the list of active quotes that are in the carts, take a look at the table `log_quote`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you say shopping cart items you mean order items right??

I'll do this with sql because you need to migrate the info, if you need as collection to use on magento let me know.

```
SELECT o.customer_id , p.name
FROM sales_flat_quote as o
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_quote_item as i ON i.quote_id = o.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 as p ON i.product_id = p.entity_id

$list = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
foreach($list as $li){
    $itens = $li->getItemsCollection(); //here we have the itens;
    $li->getCustomer()->getName; // here we have the customer name.
    foreach($itens as $i){
       $i->getName();//itens name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the getModel methods instead of querying the DB?. Something like `$items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();`

Comment: sorry but it didn't work for me, `$li->getAllItems();` is empty. I also tried the your SQL way but it returns repeated values. Sorry my mistake, they are not "repeated" since is an order, I just want the user's carts

Comment: its becouse i dont use 1.7 version i make this code based on 1.5 but should work, this method probably changed the signature, go to Mage_Sales_Model_Order and look for "item" and change the method for the right one. and the rest should work.

Comment: But with getAllItems you got error or just dont come nothing?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, they are not "repeated" since is an order, I just want the user's carts, not all the orders

Comment: Carts don't have aways customer with him becouse that i make the code to bring order, but if you change the word order by quote you can get the cart. Mage::getModel('sales/quote').

Comment: In quote you have change the method to get customer name to: $li->getCustomer()->getName();

Comment: With the quote one I can get the customer, and the price, but not the product.

Comment: With quote you'll do $li->getItemsCollection(); i'll edit the code to quote

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work with getItemsCollection, tried with getItems() but the code doesn't return the expected result

Comment: If you can make it work with quote in SQL, I'll appreciate it

Comment: ok, edited the answer. the cart and the order are virtually the same

Comment: with that SQL I still have repeated values, I mean, various sets of the same 2 values

Comment: Its becouse the information on database are duplicated, or something.

Comment: lol, thousant of right things and no positive? if you want i work for you, just hire me.

Comment: Actually none of your methods actually worked fully. If you're expecting good feedback you should provide full working answers

Comment: If you need 100% precise Answer pls send your DB dump becouse the code is that one, worked here fine. but if you need something else let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at quote tables: `sales_flat_quote`, `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_quote_item_option`

Comment: I tried the the SQL solution of the other answer involving 2 of those tables but still I get repeated values

Comment: So, then just add GROUP BY product id to your SQL solution